# basic gganimate leads to "error in device . . . unused argument (useS4 = FALSE)"

Tags: r, gganimate

I'm trying to get started with gganimate, plugging the fundamental example from the cheatsheet into an RMD.
But I'm not able to knit to html.

I have simply the following:

````
---
title: "My RMD"
author: "Your Name"
date: "The Date"
output:
  html_document: default

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE, purl=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

``` {r}

suppressMessages(library(ggplot2))
suppressMessages(library(gganimate))


a <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price))
a <- a + geom_point()

anim_a <- a + transition_states(color, transition_length = 3, state_length = 1)
show(anim_a)

```
````

Tragically, when I try to knit, I get the very cryptic error:

> Error in device(files[i], ...) : unused argument (useS4 = FALSE)
> Calls:  ... animate -> animate.gganim -> do.call ->
> <Anonymous>

I have found advice to install png and gifski if I haven't already, and also put magick since I saw that somewhere as well.
Adding those had no effect.

_
I also googled the error message, and that combination is not out there.
There are very similar messages with "unused argument" relating to misused options in gganimate functions,
but this message is significantly different - and
we know the basic options here, from the cheatsheet, are correct, right?

_
This seems like it will be tough to figure out except by experience.
Has anyone seen a solution to this particular error?

Answer (score 0):

**Your example is close but not quite ~**

While the syntax in `transition_states()` is indeed fine, there is an important detail on the next line.

gganimate is intended to work hand-in-hand with ggplot and integrate into its syntax, so your example makes sense.  But . . .

- **gganimate does not support show()**

You need to

- **change**

  ```
  show(anim_a)
  ```
- **to**

  ```
  animate(anim_a)
  ```

_
Then the RMD should knit ok.